# Creating different types based on some criteria

Tags: c#, design-patterns, inversion-of-control

I have some code in an application that I am not really thrilled about right now. I created a few classes like so:

```
class Base
{
   // base properties ...
}

class DerivedA : Base
{
}

class DerivedB : Base
{
}
```

I have a method in my application that needs to create one of these objects (with more to come in the future) based on a string property that is stored in the database. Each one of these objects gets its data from slightly different places, but the way I'm doing it right now is just a big if block and it doesn't seem very maintainable:

```
class BaseCreator
{
    Base Create(string name)
    {
        if (name == "DerivedA" )
            return CreateDerivedA();
        else if(name == "DerivedB")
            return CreateDerivedB();
    }
}
```

What are some ways I can refactor this code to be more maintainable and make it easier to add new types in the future? I am using dependency injection (Ninject) in my application if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 1):

Inheritance trees are always difficult to maintain once they grow.  If you know up front that the tree will be large---seriously consider using composition instead of inheritance.  Especially if you're already using a DI framework, interfaces are the way to go.

Comment: I don't ever see more than a dozen types being added, but can you provide an example of what you mean. I don't see the obvious link between taking what I have an converting it to use a DI Container and constructing objects based off of a string.

Comment: The conversion should be Base from a class to an interface.  Each type of Base can implement the interface and this allows those implementations and the contract (Base, in your case) to be manageable by the requirements of interfaces.  The string, make an enum or something less error prone.  Have your DI container bind the  type (based on your new enum) to the Base contract and have the DI container resolve the interface returning you your objective.

Comment: The string is stored in the database.

Answer (score 1):

If you really must use strings, you can use reflection:

```
object GetInstance(string typeName)
{
    Type.GetType(typeName).GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes).Invoke(new object[0]);
}
```

You could also use a dictionary:

```
IDictionary<string, Func<object>> TypeMap = new Dictionary<string, Func<object>>()
{
    { "TypeA", () => new TypeA() },
    { "TypeB", () => new TypeB() },
    { "TypeC", () => new TypeC() },
};

object GetInstance(string typeName)
{
    return TypeMap[typeName]();
}
```

For others landing on this page, consider using generics, if you don't *have* to use strings:

```
T CreateInstance<T>()
    where T : new()
{
    return new T();
}
```

Comment: @GuiltShow Yes, which is why I provided you with two other methods using strings.  Remember, I'm not just answering you.  I'm answering everyone else who lands on this page.

Comment: @GuiltShow If it makes you happier, I'll say that explicitly in the answer.  Ah, sorry.  I usually post my answers in pieces.

Comment: @GuiltShow Should be better worded now.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use the abstract factory pattern which solves this problem. 
It provides an interface for creating families of related or dependent objects without specifying their concrete classes. 
http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternAbstract.aspx

Or just a factory pattern 
http://www.dotnetperls.com/factory

Answer (score 1):

I will note that your `if/else` or `switch` structure is not a bad thing. The bad thing is when you have the same `if/else` or `switch` expressed *multiple times.*

When you have nicely decoupled your code and you are programming to the interface or abstract base rather than the concrete, know that *somewhere* in your application, *something* knows how to create the particular concrete instance that you need. This can be code, it can be configuration, it can be some container, etc. But that *something* has to exist. The idea is to have that *something* existing *once.*

Your approach is fine as long as this is the only method where it exists. This class' reason to exist is that it creates the concrete instances that fulfill some interface. Its reason to change is that some other concrete implementation has been added (or removed).

Answer (score 1):

The general case can be solved by a bit of composition and the use of the Specification pattern:

```
public class Base
{
    public abstract bool IsSatisfiedBy(string name);

    // base properties ...
}

public class DerivedA : Base
{
    public override bool IsSatisfiedBy(string name)
    {
        return name == "DerivedA";
    }
}

public class DerivedB : Base
{
    public override bool IsSatisfiedBy(string name)
    {
        return name == "DerivedB";
    }
}

public class BaseCreator
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<Base> candidates;

    public BaseCreator(IEnumerable<Base> candidates)
    {
        this.candidates = candidates;
    }

    public Base Create(string name)
    {
        return this.candidates.First(c => c.IsSatisfiedBy(name));
    }
}
```

Comment: It's probably be easier to have a dictionary, but I suppose it's theoretically the same efficiency.

Comment: In this specific case it looks equivalent to a dictionary, but since you could put anything in the IsSatisfiedBy implementation, you can create some more convention-based or algorithmic solutions. For this reason, this solution is more flexible than a dictionary.

Comment: nice answer, but it requires that you hold a list of pre-instantiated classes of DerivedA and DerivedB and the semantics of Create are slightly broken, since you are not Creating but returning an existing instance that matches a predicate condition, this could be misleading.

Comment: When we are talking about Services, it's often more correct to talk about *selecting* them than *creating* them, but if they must be created for some reason or other, you could always modify this example to use a list of potential factories.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a general answer to this question. Abstract Factory may be correct, but it all depends on what the difference is between these implementations and how you use them.

It could well be that you should be using Template, Strategy, State or any other similar pattern. Look into them, and definitely Abstract Factory, and decide on a pattern that suits your specific scenario.